# sort according to arrival time in FCFS scheduling algorithm

Tags: c++

I'm working on my project about scheduling algorithm (FCFS) in C++. All the things left I need to do is gantt chart.  Here's an example:

[image: gantt chart example]

I can sort if it is only the arrival time but I'm getting confused on how to sort the process id according to arrival time.

This is what I try to use to sort the process id based on arrival time.

```
for (i=0; i<n-1; i++){
     for (j=0; j<n-i-1; j++){
            if (at[i]>at[i+1]){
                temp = pid[i+1];
                pid[i+1] = pid[i];
                pid[i] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why are your two data structures separate? Why aren't they in a class? Also you never use `j` in this code, making the inner loop useless

Comment: @UnholySheep oh god, thank you very much for pointing out that `j`, That's so stupid of me.  I tweak my code a little got it working now.

Answer (score 1):

Just one of many implementations, that can be given for an answer

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

class Process {
public:
    Process(std::string name, size_t pid) : name(name), pid(pid) {}
    std::string name {"default"};
    size_t pid {0};
};

int main() {
    std::vector<Process> v {
        Process {"p1", 1}, Process {"p2", 2}, Process {"p6", 6},
        Process {"p3", 3}, Process {"p0", 0}
    };

    std::sort(
        v.begin(),
        v.end(),
        [](const Process & a, const Process & b) -> bool {
            return a.pid > b.pid;
        }
    );

    for (auto value : v)
        std::cout << value.name << ": " << value.pid << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use STL to solve the problem in a much easier way without using 2 loops

```
#include <iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;
int main() {
//The first part of pair contains the arrival time for every PID and
// the second part contains the PID NO.
vector<pair<int,int> >v;
 v.push_back({4,1});
 v.push_back({3,2});
 v.push_back({5,3});
  //sort the vector according to arrival time 
 sort(v.begin(),v.end());
  //Your Solution
 cout<<v[0].second<<" "<<v[1].second<<" "<<v[2].second<<endl;
return 0;
```

}